# Finding all spaces in html tags with one regular expression

Tags: html, regex, tags

I have a user generated *HTML* valid text in which I need to find and replace all spaces that are **inside** html tags. Please don't ask me why, I am just looking for the regular expression that finds all spaces between the `<` and `>` of *HTML* tags.

Comment: Rule 1) never parse HTML with RegEx. Rule 2) if you want to parse HTML with RegEx see rule 1.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Won't that turn `<a href="foo">` into `<ahref="foo">` and break it?

Comment: You will mangle your html if you do this.

Comment: To be fair to Sander, @Quentin, it hasn't been said WHAT will happen to those spaces, but that is the logical conclusion

Comment: @freefaller He did say "replace".

Comment: Yes @MrLister, but he didn't say with what

Comment: Ah, I misread it as "remove". Knowing the usecase would be helpful though. At the moment the question just triggers the "Why do you want to do that?" "What use is that to anyone else?" and "Don't go near regex!" responses. (See also [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Yes, I guessed that would happen, that's why I stated "please don't ask me why", because if I start explaining that, all answers will go off topic. I am just looking for the Regex guru that can give me a Regex for this. But for those who are curious (and again please don't comment on this fact) I need it to sort out the final small bugs in a HTML compare tool I created. I need to temporarily encode the spaces in the HTML tags with a special char, so that I can let my code work with all the other spaces in the text normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with callback function. Example with PHP (version >= 5.3)

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~<(.*?)>~s', 
    function ($match) {
        return '<' . str_replace(' ', 'your_replacement', $match[1]) . '>';
    },
    $str
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to never use Regex for parsing the HTML.

Give the `HTMLAgilityPack` a look into: **[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the regular expression solution I created the following explode implode solution:

```
$tags_split_array = explode("<", $htmltext);
foreach($tags_split_array as $key => $tagpart) {
    $tagpart_array = explode(">", $tagpart);
    $tagpart_array[0] = str_replace(" ", "ψ", $tagpart_array[0]);
    $tags_split_array[$key] = implode(">", $tagpart_array);
}
$htmltext= implode("<", $tags_split_array);
```

But still the regex solution is much better so I will use that.